# Allow my Kubuntu laptop to connect to wireless w/o asking for my KWallet password?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, kwallet

Is there a way to setup my laptop so when I login it automatically connects to my wireless w/o asking for the password for KWallet to unlock the keystore to connect?
I'm sure I'm mixing terms from my Mac, but hope you all understand.

Basically upon login, my laptop would connect w/o prompt to my wireless network.

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

There's a way not to be prompted to type kwallet's password every time you want to use a Wireless connection.

1. Right click on network manager icon and select "Network management arrangement" (text may differ a little bit since I am not used an English version of Kubuntu)
2. Select "Other" icon from the recently opened dialog box.
3. Select to save the passwords on a separate unencrypted file
4. Apply changes

That's all. Please be warned that this option may suppose a possible security breach since all passwords are stored without encryption.

Comment: Can KWallet be "unlocked" upon login?  SO the password is still stored and encrypted but at least on the wireless side of things I'm not prompted for a password?

Comment: Or maybe is there a way to connect to the wireless before I login?  Like as the computer boots it connects and I would be online before I login?  In case of a reboot the computer would automatically connect to wireless w/o requiring a login?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the answer to these questions.

Comment: On Kubuntu 16.04: Right-click on the WiFi icon and click "Configure Network Connections...". A "Connection editor" window show a list of saved connections. Right-click on the WiFi network you want to work with, and click "Edit..." from the drop-down menu. This opens a new window. There should be a "Wi-Fi Security" tab. Click on that. It should list a security option and a password, and the password field should have an eyeball icon and a disk icon both on the right. Click the disk icon to save the password.  Choose "Store password and make it available for all users (not encrypted)". Done!

Comment: @jjesse: That might make a good question in a separate post. .

Answer (score 1):

In kubuntu:

-click network widget > setting icon
-right click your wifi connection > edit
-general configuration tab
-check 'all users may connect to this network'
-press OK

Answer (score 1):

## Kubuntu 16.04

Note: The following is my adaptation of @ccamara's answer, which didn't *quite* work as written on my system. If you upvote this answer, you should upvote theirs as well.

#### Introduction

KWallet needs a password to decrypt its stored passwords, which includes your WiFi password. To avoid having to type a password each time, you can store your WiFi password in an unencrypted file. This allows KWallet to use the WiFi password without dycrypting it.

#### Warning

If you do this, know that this opens a possible security hole, as any user on your computer could access this file and learn your wifi password.

- Do not use this approach if you need the wifi password to be hidden from other users on this computer.
- If you use your wifi password for other accounts (not recommended!), you may want to hide it so that others would not learn your password and be able to access your other accounts with it.

Of course, it would only be vulnerable to somebody who could access your computer. You *probably don't* need to worried about your neighbors stealing your wifi password through this approach because they *probably* will not have access to your computer.

### Steps

Right-click on the WiFi icon and click "Configure Network Connections...".

A "Connection editor" window show a list of saved connections. Right-click on the WiFi network you want to work with, and click "Edit..." from the drop-down menu.

This opens a new window, with a "Wi-Fi Security" tab. Click on that tab.

There should be a drop-down menu of security options and a password field. The password field should have an eyeball icon and a disk icon both on the right. Click the disk icon to save the password.

Choose "Store password and make it available for all users (not encrypted)".

*Done!*

Answer (score 0):

I thought there should be a better way than saving into an unencrypted file, and found that one may edit the connection and check that **it may be used by all users**.  Then, the password will not be stored in the current user's KDE wallet, but somewhere deeper in the NetworkManager infrastructure (presumably in a file only readable by priviledged users, possibly obfuscated as well).  In any case, the connection will be automatically initiated for all users, without any further password prompts.