# Tell KDE to store network secret in unencrypted file via commandline

Tags: wireless, kwallet

I have run into a situation where I'd like to get my wireless working without the benefit of a monitor, by sshing in.  I have KDE on the system, have enabled autologin for one of the users and would now like to set up the wireless to automatically connect without kwallet prompting me for a password.  (That way I can ditch my ethernet cable and move my computer out of the way).

I assume that this requires me to store the password in an unencrypted file; that's just fine with me.  I've run across some ways to do that via the gui ([such as this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/224716)) but, for my circumstances, I need to be able to pull this off via ssh.

Would anyone know how to accomplish this?  It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @virtualxtc It's certainly close, but the key point is that I'd like to use knetworkmanager to accomplish this, as it's aready insatlled and working.  Still, I'll see if there's a tip in that link that I might be able to include in what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; knetworkmanager is a graphical front end for network-manager, and thus is not controlled via the command line.  However, there are tools for managing network manager, see this post:
[Connecting to wireless networks from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150972/connecting-to-wireless-networks-from-command-line)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Does that mean that the question is indeed the same as the one you linked to?

Comment: it's actually a dupe of the article I linked above.